# WebKit bug? Hover state does not get applied to content inserted via CSS

Tags: css, webkit

There appears to be a WebKit bug that does not apply a hover state to content inserted via the `content` property in CSS.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

```
a:before {
    content: "Hover Over Me";
}
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wdmedal/X4gjL/1/

---

**Conclusion**: This bug seems to only affect `inline` elements.

**Workaround**: Set the display type of the element to `inline-block` (or another display type).

Comment: Seriously, WebKit needs to stop making IE8 look good in standards compliance with all these bugs (although to be fair, IE8+ doesn't seem to handle `:hover` on `display: table` and friends either whereas WebKit does just fine). This isn't even some brand-new CSS3 stuff...

Comment: Adding content to the link in the HTML makes it work?

Comment: @Whymarrh: Yes, but you still won't be able to trigger the hover style if you hover the generated content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me http://jsfiddle.net/X4gjL/5/

```
a:before {
    content: "Hover Over Me";
}
a.foo:hover {
    color: red;
}
a.foo
{
    display:block;
}​
```

-------------EDIT---------

Thanks to [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) for pointing this out, making it inline-block doesn't make the width 100% by default like block.   http://jsfiddle.net/X4gjL/6/

```
a:before {
    content: "Hover Over Me";
}
a.foo:hover {
    color: red;
}
a.foo
{
    display:inline-block;
}​
```

Comment: I just realized this also. The bug only seems to affect `inline` elements. I was about to answer my own question but you beat me to it!

Comment: You can also make it an inline block so it doesn't stretch across the entire page width.

Comment: @BoltClock you're right, I edited the answer and added that for future users.  Made sure to cite my source.  Thanks!